# Regex to validate a password in order to create a DFA

Tags: regex, passwords, dfa

I need to create a regex to validate a password and then create a DFA with it.
The sets are:

> a = {a,...,z}
>   | A = {A,...,Z}
>   | d = {0,...,9}

The criteria are:

> Must begin with a letter (doesn't matter if upper or lower case).
>   | Must contain at least 1 upper case.
>   | Must contain at least 1 lower case.
>   | Must contain at least 1 number.

So far, I've come with the following Regex:

```
(aa\*(AA\*a\*dd\*|dd\*a\*AA\*)|AA\*(aa\*A\*dd\*|dd\*A\*aa\*))(a|A|d)\*
```

Is it correct?

Comment: It's a theoretical question. It does not have a unique dialect at all, It's a general regex expression.

Also, it's a homework really brainstormed >_<.

Comment: You don't have to build all alternations. Use lookaheads.

Answer (score 0):

The inner parts of your expression are slightly wrong. For example, with `AA*a*dd*`, you trying to check the case where it begins with 'a' and then 'A' occurs before 'd', but this does not match "aAaAd". Here is a correct version:

```
(aa*(d(a|d)*A|A(a|A)*d)|AA*(d(A|d)*a|a(A|a)*d))(a|A|d)*
```

The DFA you should do as an exercise. It should have 7 states including start and end. Think about establishing one state for each combination of characters that you have left to match.